# Проблема передачи двух переменных в функцию js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой php

```
echo "<button onclick=func($value)><button>";
```

и js

```
<script>
   function func(id)
   {
      alert(id);
   }
</script>
```

Именно в таком варианте работает, если просто чисто в переменной. Но если переменная содержит строку, то передаю так

```
echo "<button onclick=func('$value')><button>";
```

Но если в переменной строка с из двух слов - неработает. Как передать переменную со строкой из нескольких слов, с пробелами?
И как сделать такой вариант:

```
$value = 1;
$value2 = 'aaa bbb';
echo "<button onclick=func($value, $value2)></button>";
```

с таким js

```
<script>
  function(value, value2)
  {
     alert(value);
     alert(valu2);

  }
</script>
```

Я понимаю, что вопрос может быть тупой, но простите меня заранее.

Comment: В кавычки, двойные. Внутри строки кавычки экранировать.

Comment: В консоль выводит ошибку - SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: Экранирование производится с помощью обратной косой черты. \"

Comment: Я так и сделал - echo "<button onclick=func(\"$value2\")></button>";

Comment: К сведению, в PHP можно совмещать html и php. Вместо `echo "<button onclick=func(\"$value2\")></button>";` можно написать `?><button onclick="javascript:func('<?= $value2 ?>');">Button</button><?php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы так должно работать: https://ideone.com/wIbXYF

```
<?php
$value = 'abc"def';
echo "<button onclick=\"func(" . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($value)) . ")\"><button>";
```

Comment: Кавычки не экранированы.

Comment: @Adokenai, исправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @IZrchnsk, исправил. А то что-то я муть написал сначала.